# sequalize Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Model<any, any>'

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have an entity

```
@Table({tableName: 'EducationEntity'})
export class EducationEntity extends Model<EducationEntity> {

}
```

Im trying to do: `EducationEntity.build(plainObject as any);` to build model from plain object.

I am getting the error:

```
src/research/research.service.ts:165:51 - error TS2684: The 'this' context of type 'typeof EducationEntity' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type '(new () => EducationEntity) & typeof Model'.
  Type 'typeof EducationEntity' is not assignable to type 'typeof Model'.
    The types returned by 'init(...)' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Model<any, any>'.
```

What is that, EducationEntity is a model ?

Thakns

Comment: You are trying to have a class extend a Model with a typeof the same class. You need to define a different interface.

Comment: @doublesharp can you please explain with small example? thanks